# How do I stop all 262,144 kernels if I find my answer

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I am using pyopencl to find a certain pixel in a 512 x 512 (262,144 pixels) image. I am starting (512,512), when I run my program and comparing the pixel's neighbors to a known group of neighbors. I am doing image synthesis.  I don't want to wait around for the remaining kernels to run if I find my group of pixels within a kernel. Is there a way to terminate the rest of the running kernels with a kernel program ?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: I think there is something wrong in what you call "kernel". Do you mean you want to stop the ongoing kernel when a workitem has the result?

Answer (score 1):

When you queue a kernel with many work items, it gets divided up into work groups and threads which keep the GPU busy. Really large global sizes start as many threads as they can and issue new ones when the old ones finish. So you could find the smallest global size that still performs well, and queue many of those (instead of one large one), but also be checking on the results of the previous ones you queued (use events to know when they are done, and read back memory to get their results). When you get the correct answer, stop queueing kernels.

so instead of this:

```
queue entire job (say, 4096 x 4906)
```

do:

```
do
{
   queue some work (say, 32 x 32)
   check if any of the prior work queued is done and check if it got the answer
}
while (no more work OR answer found)
```

You'll need to figure out the right tradeoff between the size of the smaller jobs and the overhead of checking their results versus extra work done.

Answer (score 0):

First thought it to have some sort of global memory flag that each kernel can read and set.  This approach requires atomicity, so make sure to use the `atomic_` functions.

```
 __kernel void t(__global int *Data,
                 __global int *Flag){
      if(atomic_max(*Flag, 0) == 0){
          //perform calc on Data
          if(PixelsFound){
               //Set the flag to +1
               *Flag = atomic_inc(*Flag);
          }
      }
 }
```

Community, feel free to comment if this is known not to work!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a big issue and problem of parallelism.

```
What to do when one of your parallel threads has already the answer to the problem?
```

OpenCL does not allow to control the kernel execution. Not even at host level. And this is a big problem. However it is how it has to be, since, if the work items do not run freely detached one from another then it is not fully parallel.

The only solution is to split the computation into small parts and check the completion of each of them. But, sometimes the parts are already very small (like in your case 512x512 is quite small).

In your specific case I would process everything (512x512), after that I would use another kernel to get the final results out of the 512x512 set.